# How to clear setTimeout() and jQuery fadeOut() before either are done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this showMessage function:

```
function showMessage(message) {
    $('#my_message').show();
    $('#my_message').html(message);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#my_message').fadeOut();},
        2000);
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly if it's called again before the setTimeout() and/or the fadeOut() have completed. ie. it doesn't start over again and wait 2 seconds - it stutters a bit as you can imagine. How can I clear the setTimeout and the fadeOut so it works as expected?

edit:

It was suggested to use jQuery delay() instead of setTimeout(). But I don't think delay() will work properly(on jQuery delay() doc page it says delay() can't be cancelled). Here's my updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_form').submit(function() {
        $('#my_message').stop();
        $('#my_message').hide();

        $.get('/my_url',
            $('#my_form').serialize(),
            function(data) {
                showMessage(data);
            });

        return false;
    });
});

function showMessage(message) {
    $('#my_message').html(message);
    $('#my_message').show();
    $('#my_message').delay(5000).fadeOut();
}
```

So the message will show for 5 seconds and then fade. The problem is that the delay is never cancelled. For example if I submit the form once and get the message to show, and then wait 4 seconds and submit again, then the first delay will still be alive and thus the second delay looks like 1 second. So how can I make the delay always 5 seconds even if a delay is interrupted. I tried using `stop(true)` and `stop('fx', true)` but neither seemed to have any effect.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use `setTimeout` at all.  Change it to `delay`.

```
$('#form_message').delay(2000).fadeOut();
```

This will then allow you to use jquery's `stop`.

```
$('#form_message').stop();
```

`stop` also takes optional parameters which let you decide if you want to complete the animation or simply stop where it is.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: not sure if delay() will work here. jQuery docs say delay() can't be cancelled. See post edit. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried passing `true` as the first parameter?  You may not be able to stop just the delay, but I think it should be cleared if you clear the queue.

Comment: See this example.  Passing true shoudl clear the delay: http://jsfiddle.net/R4gQJ

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question:

```
var messageTimeout;
function showMessage(message) {
    clearInterval(messageTimeout);
    $('#my_message').stop().html(message).fadeTo(100, 1);
    messageTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$('#my_message').fadeOut();}, 2000);
}
```